# undo commit vs revert commit in Git (VS Code)

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

- When to undo a commit and when to revert a commit in git?
- What are the git commands to do both of them?
- How to perform both tasks using VS code (UI)?

Comment: Why grouping questions here? Better keep them focused on *one* thing, you'll have better quality answers.

Comment: I think there must be a place where all the questions should be addressed related to one question.

Answer (score 0):

Undo is to ditch **last** commit. It will not exists anymore **in the current branch**.

Command(s depending on how it is implemented in VSCode):

```
git reset --soft HEAD~
```

Or (to not keep changes in staging area):

```
git reset --mixed HEAD~
```

Revert is creating a new commit that contains all the opposite changes of the commit you will revert. So original commit and new reverting commit are in the current branch.

Command:

```
git revert <HASH_COMMIT_TO_REVERT>
```

Both strategies have pros and cons. Read about it.
The main idea is if the purpose is to fix an error just made **and the commit has still not been pushed**, undo is perfectly fine.
**If commit/history has already been pushed**, except for special cases, revert is more likely the way to go...

PS: another solution instead of undo could be just to amend the last commit...

Answer (score -1):

### A-undo commit (most recent(s))

```
undo commit-> You want to jump back
```

[image]

**Git commands:**

To undo a `local commit` in Git, you can use the `git reset` command.

**Types/Options:**

1. --mixed **(default)**
2. --soft
3. --hard

**1. --mixed:** undo commit + `unstaged the changes` and puts them back into the `working directory`.

```
git reset HEAD~
```

or

```
git reset –mixed HEAD~1  //1-> undo one most recent commit
```

or

```
git reset –mixed HEAD~2  //2-> undo two most recents commit
```

[image]

**2. --soft:** undo commit + keep the changes in the `staging area (index)`.

```
git reset --soft HEAD~
```

**3. --hard:** undo commit + `discard/remove` all the changes.

```
git reset --hard HEAD~
```

**VS Code:**

[image]

**Note1:** In all the `reset` commands, the `branch pointer` of your current branch will be moved to the previous commit (`HEAD~` refers to the commit before the current one) as shown in the above image.
Now if you want your changes in :

- the `working directory` use `--mixed` option,
- the `staging area (index)` use `--soft` option, and
- for `discard/remove` changes use `--hard` option.

**Note2:** `Undo commit **DOES NOT** creates a new commit`.

**Note3:** You should undo commit(s) if your commit(s) is/are `local`, means you did not pushed into `remote`.

### B-revert commit

```
revert commit-> You want your changes (committed) back but in a new commit
```

[image]

**Git commands:**

To undo a `published/remote commit` in Git, you can use the `git revert` command.

**Types/Options:**

1. --edit **(default)** : soft revert
2. --no-edit :hard revert

**1. --no-edit:** undo commit + creates a new commit (changes discarded in this commit)

```
git revert --no-edit commit-id/commit hash
```

**2. --edit:** undo commit + creates a new commit but you can review the changes.

```
git revert --edit commit-id/commit hash
```

**Note2:** `Revert commit ALWAYS creates a new commit`.

**Note3:** You should `revert a commit` if your commit is `remote`, which means you pushed into the `remote` branch in order to maintain  `commits history`